# Pantheios logging in C++ DLL

Tags: c++, logging

Here is scenario:

I have `testApp.cpp` that has `main` function. And this `testApp.cpp` uses `misc.dll` and `common.dll` library.

I would like to create a log to file rather than to console.

So in `testApp.cpp` `main()` function, I use the following:

```
pantheios::pantheios_init();
pantheios_be_file_setFilePath("mylogfile.log");
pantheios::log_NOTICE(" START TESTAPP");

// Call function from misc.dll and common.dll
pantheios::log_NOTICE(" END TESTAPP ");
pantheios_be_file_setFilePath(NULL);
```

This WILL create `mylogfile.log` file with content 'START TESTAPP'

NOW THE PROBLEM:

I would also like to adding logging from misc.dll and common.dll to `mylogfile.log`.
In other words, if I add log in `testMiscfunction()` in misc.dll, I would like that log from
`testMiscfunction()` to be written to mylogfile.log.
And of course, same things with common.dll.

Now here is sample of DLL Entry for misc.dll

```
#include "pantheios/pantheios.hpp" 
#include "pantheios/backends/bec.file.h" 
#include "pantheios/implicit_link/core.h"
#include "pantheios/implicit_link/be.file.h"

extern "C" const char PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY[] = "MISC_DLL"; 

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
            )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            pantheios::pantheios_init();
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;


        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;


        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            pantheios::pantheios_uninit();
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;

}
```

So now in

```
testMiscFunction() { pantheios::log_NOTICE("I am testMiscFunction"); }
```

So "I am testMiscFunction" is not being written to mylogfile.txt Question is: Why? What need to be done.

Thanks....

Comment: I don't see any issue with logging from either dll, could you perhaps precise the problem or tell us what you have tried and what went wrong ?

Comment: Here is sample code of misc.dll:

Comment: I updated the original question to include sample misc.dll code.

Answer (score 1):

The DLLs should link to Pantheios dynamically, so they'll use the same data. In this case you don't need to call Pantheios init/uninit functions from the DLL entry point (which is probably a bad idea anyway).

Comment: If I don't call iniy/unint functions from DLL entry point, Then program program crashed when testMiscFunction() call and try to write the log file. That's why I added it.

Comment: The DLLs should link to Panetheios dynamically. If they link statically they use their own instance of the library.